# ¿Cómo unir datos en un solo data frame usando R si las dimensiones de mis datos son diferentes?

Tags: r

Me encuentro haciendo web scraping y quisiera unir los resultados obtenidos en un solo data frame pero ocurre lo siguiente:
[image: Error al combinar datos en r]

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo podría unirlos si son de longitudes diferentes?. De antemano gracias por la atención brindada.

Comment: Hola 7R0N1X! Puedes editar tu pregunta para que pueda ser reproducida por las personas que quieren ayudarte? Mira éste post si quieres saber más sobre cómo realizar preguntas en stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Sería adecuado que incluyeras una muestra de las tablas. Puedes usar `dput()` sobre una parte de las tablas (`dput(head(tabla))`) o crear datos fictícios para facilitar la reproducción del problema. No es claro si quieres unir tablas que tienen las mismas columnas adicionando líneas o si quieres unir las columnas de dos tablas diferentes.

Comment: Un dato fundamental es que expliques que es lo que quieres hacer con las filas que te faltan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R tiene como estándar unir vectores que tienen el mismo número de observaciones. En casos en los que se unen vectores de diferentes magnitudes, R "recicla" los valores del vector de menor longitud.
Para unir vectores con tamaño diferente puedes incluir valores perdidos en el vector de menor tamaño y luego unir los vectores que te interesan

```
data(mtcars)

data(cars)

am <- mtcars$am

length(am)

# [1] 32

dist <- cars$dist

length(dist)

# [1] 50

# Incluyendo valores "NA" en el vector de menor tamaño

len <- length(dist)

length(am) <- len

length(am)

# [1] 50
```

```
df <- cbind.data.frame(am, dist)

head(df)
am dist
1  1    2
2  1   10
3  1    4
4  0   22
5  0   16
6  0   10
```